# Solve $x^2+y^3+z^4=\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{3}+\frac{z}{4}\right)^3$

Tags: number-theory

> Find all nonnegative integer solutions of the equation $x^2+y^3+z^4=\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{3}+\frac{z}{4}\right)^3$.

**Attempt:**

Two solutions are $(x,y,z) = (0,0,0),(8,0,0)$. I want to prove that there are no others, i.e. $y = z = 0$.

Suppose for sake of contradiction that there is some solution $(x,y,z)$ with $z \neq 0$ (we do a similar proof for $y \neq 0$). Simplifying and rearranging the equation gives $$1728(x^2+y^3+z^4) = (6x+4y+3z)^3.$$ Now let $x = da, y = db, z = dc$ where $d = \gcd(x,y,z)$. Then the equation becomes $$1728(d^2a^2+d^3b^3+d^4c^4) = d^3(6a+4b+3c)^3.$$ Then $$1728(a^2+db^3+d^2c^4) = d(6a+4b+3c)^3.$$

Comment: You can write the last equation as a quadratic equation in $d$, apply the general law and try to get contradiction!